How to make Matplotlib title centered on graph and legend box outside of graph
I have a graph plot with the legends outside of the plot. I have the title centered on the graph plot, and I want to keep it centered. The problem is, the title only centers around the graph plot, not the graph plot AND the legends as a group. So it makes my plot always looking skewed:
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/dOlpS.png
Is there a way to shift the graph plot to the side so that the title appears centered on both?
Minimal reproduction:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0,10,1000)
y1 = np.sin(x)
y2 = np.cos(x)

plt.plot(x,y1)
plt.plot(x,y2)
plt.title("A very long title that makes the graph shorter than the title itself, it's so long it makes me sick to the core")
plt.legend(["sin x", "cos x"], bbox_to_anchor = [1,0.5], loc = "center left", fontsize = 20)
plt.show()


It was nice of you to add a minum reproducible example. I hope I was able to answer your question.

Your approach is equivalent to doing the following in matplotlib's object framework.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(constrained_layout=True)

ax.plot(x,y1)
ax.plot(x,y2)
ax.legend(["sin x", "cos x"], bbox_to_anchor = [1,0.5], loc = "center left", fontsize = 20)
ax.set_title("A very long title that makes the graph shorter than the title itself,\n it's so long it makes me sick to the core.\n")


Basically, the title is being assigned to the actual plot (the ax object). What your require is for the title to be assigned to the image as whole which will encompass the plot and legend (that is the figure object). This would be the new result.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(constrained_layout=True)

ax.plot(x,y1)
ax.plot(x,y2)
ax.legend(["sin x", "cos x"], bbox_to_anchor = [1,0.5], loc = "center left", fontsize = 20)
fig.suptitle("A very long title that makes the graph shorter than the title itself,\n it's so long it makes me sick to the core.\n")



Oh wow excellent! That perfectly answers my question. Thank you
